# How to calculate no of days based on dates

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

so this is regarding the picture below where the flights are flying from origin and destination. What I am unable to understand is how the days are calculated, meaning how we are saying that a flight is flying on Monday or Tuesday or Web etc based on the picture below.

Comment: The data in the picture doesn't make any sense to me. First row is valid on Wed, 16 Nov 22 and Thu, 17 Nov 22 - but the columns Tue and Fri are checked. So I doubt that ValidityFrom/To has really sth to do with the checked weekdays... (It would fit for flight 2222 but not in general)

Answer (score 1):

Have you even tried googling?

The DateTime class has a format setting for getting the Day of the Week:
(Google Search: "get the weekday from date c#")
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-extract-the-day-of-the-week-from-a-specific-date

If its because you mean to calculate it in general, then:
(Google Search: "calculate the day of the week for any date")
https://www.almanac.com/how-find-day-week

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL query to return the day of the week:

SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE());

Syntax: DATENAME(interval, date)

It will return the day of the week written out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to determine how many days between the dates you can use the SQL DATEDIFF function:

SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25');

Syntax: DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2)